# Proper way of contrusting scrapy start_requests()

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape the TOP TEN RELEASES table from [Torrenting.com](http://www.torrenting.com), and I have made a crawler for that purpose, but you first need to be logged in to the site. The initial data that I have scraped was basically nothing, so I started rebuilding mine `torrent_spider.py` for that purpose and because I am new to web scraping I am stuck whit this issue.

I am reading the Scrapy docs on this and I have found that  `start_requests()` will help me connect to torrenting and start scraping for the table.

Mine question is, can someone explain to me how do I return the `https://www.torrenting.com/browse.php` page after mine spider is logged in, so I can start scraping the wanted data.

This is `torrent_spider.py`:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class TorrentSpider(Spider):
    """ TorrentSpider who will Scrape the Top Then Relese Table. """
    name = "torrenting"
    allowed_domains = ["torrenting.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.torrenting.com/browse.php",
    ]

    def start_request(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.torrenting.com/login.php?returnto=Login",
                                    formdata={'user': 'example', 'pass': 'somepass'},
                                    callback = self.logged_in)

    def logged_in(self, response):
        pass


    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: Why not just return a request to `https://www.torrenting.com/browse.php` under the `logged_in` callback?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the example you are talking about.

Comment: I think I understood what are you trying to explain to me. Is this common practice for login form when web scraping site's?

Comment: Pretty much. You often have a request and callback to handle logging in and the rest of the requests are generated from that callback.

Comment: Ok, I have found some examples from which I can benefit,  and make things work.